# Oracle Cloud Always Free - APEX not working - ORDS problem?

Tags: oracle, rest, cloud, oracle-apex

ORDS gives me below error.

I did not change any configuration. I also tried restarting the whole shebang. Anyone have a clue on what to do?

```
503 Service Unavailable

The connection pool named: |ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaa<redacted>|re| is not correctly configured, due to the following error(s): 
Exception occurred while getting connection: 
oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: 
Cannot get Connection from Datasource: 
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error: 
ORA-12529, TNS:connect request rejected based on current filtering rules
```

[image]

Comment: What region is this? The issue is a network ACL not allowing ORDS to connect to your db

Comment: Hello - thank you for reading my message and taking the trouble to reply. Really appreciate it! Its all in Germany Central Frankfurt. Weird thing is dat I definately did not change anything in that area.

Comment: Ooh I now realised what I did to deserve this, just dont know how to fix it. I changed the password for the database user (because it had an @ in it). @'s and oracle databases are a pain in the a$$. So now the ORDS (im guessing) is trying to make a database connection with the old password. Any ideas on how I can change that configuration?

Comment: That’s not this error.  This error is networking. You have to get me the full ocid or file a ticket to get it fixed.

Comment: Well - meantime I created the whole instance etc. anew. Deleting the old one. Hope it doesnt happen again :). Should it happen again I'll try and see whats really wrong.

Comment: It's nothing you did at all. This specific error is a bug in the system, If encountered again, log a ticket to resolve it.

Comment: Thank you Kris, thats good to know for future reference.